# SSIS Data flow task and "mixed" select

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, dataflow

Can't get following to work. Notice it worked just fine using SQL Server 2000 DTS package.

AXDB is external server (SQL Server 2000 Enterprise) and OLAP being the local database, SQL Server 2008 R2 standard (olap is used select statement getting the date to pass on the external SQL Server). Adding server name doesn't help.

Servers are linked if it matters, probably not.

If I just write the date there instead of trying to get it via select statement it works fine as expected.

How to achieve what I want here, notice I have about 100 such packages.

Pics are here:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/Ysl9D]

Error:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/puP4H]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `'` ticks from around the sub-select:

```
...AND DATEPHYSICAL <= (SELECT lkpv FROM OLAP.dbo.laadimisaeg)
```

Right now your select is being read as a string, and that string is trying to be compared to a date.

Comment: Hi,

thx for the recommendation, unfortunately this doesn't work also. Modified a bit the select more.Access denied basically is the result, eetll-bi-srv\eetllbisrv is the local sql server instance where i'm running the query.

Any recommendations how to get same logic working in some other ways ? 
I want to use masterdata table, i don't want to write the dates in those selects and modify them all the time.

[see the result][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fKzV.png

Comment: @user1371966 Two things.. First, removing the `'` ticks will solve your error in question, so you shouldn't need that convert (assumging `lkpv` is a date type).  Second, instead of using the server path `eetll-bi-srv\eetllbisrv`, use the linked server name that you set it up as, from the AXDB SSMS.  Since you're executing this on the AXDB server.

Comment: @user1371966 I highly recommend testing the query from SSMS while connected to AXDB.  That is how SSIS will execute the query, and your error messages will probably make more sense if you take that approach to testing. :)